# Is there any possibility to reduce routes in laravel4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to know is there any possibility to reduce routes for same controller in laravel4.

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('emp/add-employee/','EmpController@addEmployee');

Route::post('emp/add-employee/','EmpController@addEmployee');

Route::get('emp/edit-employee/{id}','EmpController@editEmployee');

Route::post('emp/edit-employee/{id}','EmpController@editEmployee');

Route::get('emp/view-employee/{id}','EmpController@viewEmployee');
```

is there any posibility to do reduce...?

Answer (score 5):

Your route actions look like the ones you'd find in a [RESTful Resource Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers). So you could use this:

```
Route::resource('emp', 'EmpController', array('only' => array('create', 'store', 'edit', 'update', 'show')));
```

This will of course require you to rename the controller methods accordingly and the route paths will be a little different, but you'd have a more compact route definition and consistent naming. Below are the routes that are generated by the `Route::resource` definition above.

```
+-----------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| GET  emp/create             | emp.create    | EmpController@create    |
| POST emp                    | emp.store     | EmpController@store     |
| GET  emp/{id}               | emp.show      | EmpController@show      |
| GET  emp/{id}/edit          | emp.edit      | EmpController@edit      |
| PUT  emp/{id}               | emp.update    | EmpController@update    |
+-----------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

So you'd have to rename your controller method names like so:

```
GET : addEmployee()  -> create() // shows the add form
POST: addEmployee()  -> store()  // processes the add form when submitted
GET : editEmployee() -> edit()   // shows the edit form
POST: editEmployee() -> update() // processes the edit form when submitted
GET : viewEmployee() -> show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use controller routes.

```
Route::controller('emp', 'EmpController');
```

Now you just have to rename the functions within your controller to also represent the method used like this:

```
public function getAddEmloyee()
public function postAddEmloyee()
public function getEditEmployee($id)
etc.
```

See also the [Laravel docs for controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers)

Comment: Your function syntax is wrong -- used `()` not `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `Route::match()`. This will allow you to specify `GET` and `POST` in a single route call, like so:

```
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], 'emp/edit-employee/{id}','EmpController@editEmployee');
```

You can also use `Route::all()` which will match any type request, which includes `GET` and `POST` and also any other HTTP verbs that may be specified, if that's what you want.